# Batch script not working(using notepad++ for this)

Tags: windows, batch-file, notepad++

Basically, I'm making a script that's like one of those "pick up key" or "hit monster" type game...

Here's the problem. I do the function

```
:beginning2
cls
echo You're in a room with a broken glass, a chest, a mirror, a counter with a small object on it, and a door.
echo What do you want to do?
set /p beginning2=Action:

if "%beginning2%"=="look at counter" goto counter
```

it should go to "counter" which is this part of the script.

```
:counter
cls
echo There is a small object on this counter.
echo It appears to be a key.
set /p counter=Action:

if "%counter%"=="pick up key" goto beginning3
```

Here's the entire script.

```
@echo off
color 0a
:beginning1
cls
title Adventure
echo You're in a room with a broken glass, a chest, and a mirror.
echo The room has no light.
echo What do you want to do?
set /p input=Action:

if "%input%"=="open chest" goto chest
if "%input%"=="look at mirror" goto mirror

:beginning2
cls
echo You're in a room with a broken glass, a chest, a mirror, a counter with a small object on it, and a ab door.
echo What do you want to do?
set /p beginning2=Action:

if "%beginning2%"=="look at counter" goto counter

:beginning3
cls
echo You're in a room with a broken glass, a chest, a mirror, a counter with nothing on it, and a door.
echo You also hold a key.
echo What do you want to do?
set /p beginning3=Action:

if "%beginning3%"=="open chest" goto chest2
if "%beginning3%"=="look at counter" goto counter

:beginning4
cls
echo You're in a room with a broken glass, an opened chest, a mirror, a counter with nothing on it, and a door.
echo You also hold a key.
echo What do you want to do?
set /p beginning4=Action:

if "%beginning%"=="open door" goto door

:chest
cls
echo The chest is locked. What do you want to do now?
set /p chest=Action:

if "%chest%"=="back" goto beginning1
if "%chest%"=="look at mirror" goto mirror

:chest2
cls
echo You hold a key, and a chest appears infront of you.
echo What do you want to do now?
set /p chest2=Action:

if "%chest2%"=="open chest" goto chest3

:chest3
cls
echo The chest clicks open!
echo In it appears to be another key, but slightly bigger.
echo What do you want to do now?
set /p chest3=Action:

if "%chest3%"=="back" goto beginning4

:mirror
cls
echo You look in the mirror.
echo You see nothing because the room has no light.
echo What do you want to do now?
set /p mirror=Action:

if "%mirror%"=="turn on lights" goto lights
if "%mirror%"=="back" goto beginning1

:lights
cls
echo You turned on the lights!
echo You've revealed a counter with a small object on it, and now there is light in the mirror.
set /p lights=Action:

if "%lights%"=="look at mirror" goto mirror2

:mirror2
cls
echo You look at a mirror, you see yourself with a pen mark on your arm that says "0212"
set /p mirror2=Action:

if "%mirror2%"=="back" goto beginning2

:counter
cls
echo There is a small object on this counter.
echo It appears to be a key.
set /p counter=Action:

if "%counter%"=="pick up key" goto beginning3

:door
cls
echo You go to the door with a key, and open it. It clicks open simply.
```

Please help me, as it is so frustrating. It's weird because it simply says "goto counter" but it just doesn't work with me.

Comment: Off-topic: how comes that you are making game in batch file? Why don't you use normal programming language? Even with Perl with input and output in cmd it will be much easier to develop game.

Comment: If your making a console based game, I would recommend python. Fast, simple and easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

When using if statements, they are by default case-sensitive. Use `/i` to change this:

```
set /p beginning2=Action:

if /i "%beginning2%"=="look at counter" goto counter
```

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the control flow of your program and this is the options tree of it:

```
:beginning1 (broken glass, a chest, and a mirror)
- "open chest": goto chest
- "look at mirror": goto mirror
- else:
:beginning2 (broken glass, a chest, a mirror, a counter with..., and a ab door)
- "look at counter": goto counter
- else:
:beginning3 (broken glass, a chest, a mirror, a counter with nothing..., and a door)
- "open chest": goto chest2
- "look at counter": goto counter
- else:
:beginning4 (broken glass, an opened chest, a mirror, a counter with nothing, and a door)
- "open door": goto door
- else:
:chest (chest is locked)
- "back": goto beginning1
- "look at mirror": goto mirror
- else:
:chest2 (chest appears infront of you)
- "open chest": goto chest3
- else:
:chest3 (chest clicks open)
- "back": goto beginning4
- else:
:mirror (look in the mirror)
- "turn on lights": goto lights
- "back": goto beginning1
- else:
:lights (turned on lights)
- "look at mirror": goto mirror2
- else:
:mirror2 (look at a mirror)
- "back": goto beginning2
- else:
:counter (small object on counter)
- "pick up key": goto beginning3
- else:
:door (open door)
-> terminate program
```

I run your program and it behaves exactly as it was programmed. For example, at ":lights" label, if you enter "look at mirror" the program execute "goto mirror2"; otherwise, if you enter anything different than "look at mirror" the program continue with the next line, that is ":mirror2"...

I think you must insert a `goto` with an appropriate label at each line that previous scheme specify "- else:"...

You should also include the `/I` switch in all `if` commands as Monacraft indicated, unless you are sure that the user will always enter commands in lowercase letters...